# Computation of Irradiance Map using Spherical Harmonics

Tags: opengl, framebuffer, render-to-texture

I've got a question on how to compute the irradiance cubemap using Spherical Harmonics.
I want to render to the irradiance map on the GPU using a Framebuffer. To compute it, I also need the surface normal. 
How can I move the normals of my mesh to the GPU and how do I know which one I have to choose?

Comment: If you're not sure how to get surface normals on the GPU, start with that. Spherical harmonics and other advanced techniques may be out of your league until you build up the right foundations. For example, if you can't do it with cube maps, you shouldn't be using spherical harmonics.

Comment: Thanks mate, but I think I am just on the wrong track. 
My understanding of OpenGL isn't deep indeed. But I know the mathematical things, so yeah.

The problem is that I don't want to render the scene, I want to render to a cubemap. So I can't set the vertex normals, vertex position, UV coords (of the mesh) as usual with glVertexAttribPointer.
So maybe a dumb question..
How is such a task done usually?

Comment: @DaOnlyOwner: "* The problem is that I don't want to render the scene, I want to render to a cubemap. So I can't set the vertex normals, vertex position, UV coords (of the mesh) as usual with glVertexAttribPointer.*" ... why not? Everyone else does it.

Comment: You "don't want to render the scene" but you want to "render a cubemap".  This sounds like a direct contradiction to me... what do you render to an environmental cubemap, if not the scene?

Comment: I am trying to generate the irradiance map from an already exisiting cubemap - my environment map. So what I want is not rendered scene, but the blurried out environment map. 
But I guess you're probably right I should probably get a firmer grip on the core opengl. I was taught OpenGL 1.0 last year. 
Thank you anyways ;)